# Outlook. Автоматическое создание папок

Tags: outlook

Как реализовать автоматическое создание папок в Outlook?

Например: входящие письмо в заголовке содержит #666 - проверяем, если нет такой папки, то создаем её, и переносим письмо в эту папку.

Нигде не нашел возможность подстановки шаблона при фильтрации.

Comment: Попробуйте через vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из возможных реализаций вышеописанного функционала с помощью макроса, который анализирует входящие письма и запускается с помощью правил.

Детали:
1. Добавляем код макроса:

```
Option Explicit
' Основная идея:
'   Скрипт запускается в момент срабатывания Правила при получении почты.
'   Если Тема письма (myItem.Subject) содержит значение указанное в Списке ключевых слов (LstKWrds),
'   то проверяется наличие Подпапки (mySbFldr) в Папке откуда выолнялось Правило(макрос) совпадающей
'   по имени с ключевыми словами (LstKWrds).
'   Если нет Подпапки (mySbFldr), то она создается после чего в неё переносится Письмо (myItem).
'   Если Подпапка (mySbFldr) существует, то просто в неё переносится Письмо (myItem)

Sub MailMoveToSubFolder(myItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Const myMlSrvWthAdrrs As String = "mymailaddress@yandex.ru"     'Наименование папки в Области навигации
    'Const myMlSrvWthAdrrs As String = "Файл данных Outlook"         '
    Dim myNmSpc As Outlook.NameSpace    ' пространство имен с которым работаю
    Dim myWrkFldr As Outlook.Folder     ' моя Текущая папка с которой работаю
    Dim mySbFldr As Outlook.Folder      ' Подпапка для перемещения Писем, которая будет создаваться на основании Ключевого слова

    Dim LstKwrd As String       ' список Ключевых слов по которым будет проверяться Темы входщящих писем, в случае наличия совпадения, создается папка (если не создана) и переносится в нее письмо
    Dim arKWrd() As String      ' массив для хранения Ключевых слов
    Dim i As Integer

    Set myNmSpc = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myWrkFldr = myNmSpc.Folders(myMlSrvWthAdrrs)
    LstKwrd = "#777;#Информационное сообщение;#Проект 1"
    arKWrd = Split(LstKwrd, ";")

    ' перебираем все Ключевые слова и сверяем с Темой сообщения
    For i = 0 To UBound(arKWrd)
        If InStr(myItem.Subject, arKWrd(i)) > 0 Then
            ' проверяем наличие папки соответствующей Ключевому слову (arKWrd(i))
            ' Передали управление в случае возникновения ошибки следующему оператору
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mySbFldr = myWrkFldr.Folders(arKWrd(i))
            'MsgBox ("1 " & Str(Err.Number))        ' отладка
            ' Если возникла ошибка при определении Подпапки, то следовательно Подпапки не существует и требуется её создать
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Set mySbFldr = myWrkFldr.Folders.Add(arKWrd(i))
                'MsgBox ("3 " & Str(Err.Number))    ' отладка
            End If
            ' Сбрасываем обработчик ошибок в Northing (отключили)
            On Error GoTo 0
            ' копируем Письмо в Подпапку
            myItem.Move mySbFldr
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

1.1. Постоянной `myMlSrvWthAdrrs` определяем с какой папкой в области навигации будем работать. Тестировался на адресе открытом на Яндекс.почте;

1.2. Переменной `LstKwrd` добавляем список ключевых слов по которым осуществляться анализ тем писем.

2. Создаем правило:

2.1. Выбираем условия отбора. Для обработки всех входящих писем помечаем только `"только на данном компьютере"`

[image: Выбор условий отбора]

2.2. Выбираем действия `"запустить скрипт"`, указываем -  `<Проект>.MailMoveToSubFolder`
[image: Выбор действия]

2.3. Исключения не требуются, далее задаем имя правила;
2.4. Отмечаем правила для исполнения.

[image: Включаем правила]

3. Полученный результат

[image: Результат работы макроса]

4. Возможен разбор писем размещенных в любой папке;

4.1. Выбираем необходимую папку;

4.2. Выбираем правило и принудительно выполняем.

5. Ограничения скрипта:

5.1. Не исключена возможность переноса одного и того же письма в Подпапку;

5.2. Список ключевых слов храниться в коде макроса.